# Separate parts of string with explode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get and display some data from the Wordpress database if the checkbox is checked using

`echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' value='" .$item->get_name() .$item->get_quantity() . $item->get_total() ."'>";`

and printing it out using: 
$test = $_POST['productinfo'];

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode(",", $test[$i]);
echo "Name- ".$name;
echo "<br>";
echo "Quantity ".$quantity;
echo "<br>";
echo "Total ".$total;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br/>";

}
```

but the issue is that quantity and total are stuck together in a string at I cannot print the separate, is there a way to separate them from each other, it prints out like this currently, at the end 1 being the quantity and 279 being the total. [image: it prints out like this]

Comment: Sounds like you should use a Regular Expression to extract the tokens, that allows you flexibility in the pattern. Take a look at `preg_match()` for that.

Comment: You can text me if you want on comments if still it is not working for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try separating the strings with an **unusual** character, for example the '_' if it isn't contained in the name of the product (or the "|" for example)

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' 
      value='" .$item->get_name() . "_" . $item->get_quantity() . "_" . $item->get_total() ."'>";
```

This way you can retrieve the different values using `explode("_", $checkbox_value)`(PHP) or `checkbox_value.split("_")` (JS)

Comment: This worked, using a unusual separator made then split nicely to their supposed rows

Answer (score 0):

Just add ."|". (or something that should not be in name)  in it like below. And add input hidden to explode value.

```
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='productinfo[]' onchange="setValueForHidden(this,'".$item->get_quantity() ."|" .$item->get_total()."')" value='" .$item->get_name() .$item->get_quantity() .$item->get_total() ."'>";

echo "<input type='hidden' id='productInfoVar'>";

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function setValueForHidden(item,value){
    if(item.checked){
        document.getElementById("productInfoVar").value= value

    }
}
</script>';
```

Comment: You also want a `,` between name and quantity

Comment: that worked mostly, but one product has a , in the middle of it's name, how do I avoid making that move to the quantity row? or would it be better to rename the product itself a little

Comment: question was updated while I was answering. I updated thank you point out

Comment: then I'm updating my answer

Comment: even with updated answer, the quantity and last half of the product which is separated with a , in the database print out on the same row

Answer (score 0):

In explode function you need to pass space not , in first parameter and please check that your checkbox value have space in between 
ex - it should be **"name quantity price"**  otherwise you can use any special character in between your string like **"name_quantity_price"** and then you can use explode function like explode("_", $test[$i]) it will break the string from _

**explode(",", $test[$i]) ** -> **explode(" ", $test[$i]);**

```
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($test); $i++) {
list($name, $quantity, $total) = explode(" ", $test[$i]);
echo "Name- ".$name;
echo "<br>";
echo "Quantity ".$quantity;
echo "<br>";
echo "Total ".$total;
echo "<br>";
echo "<br/>";
```

}

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp